# How to deactivate openapi logs, while compiling spring project

Tags: spring

When I compile my spring project many logs are displayed, and I want to disable the logs generating with openapi.

I expect to disble the openapi logs displying while generating the java classes with openapi, like info logs telling that class is generated.